# Why are the A51 proposal ads cut short?

Tags: bug, design, area-51, advertising

Here. Look at this:
[Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: FIRST Robotics http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/87670.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87670/first-robotics?referrer=brO2LHEsB_SEBUW2k89EDQ2)

This is the non-altered advertisement for an A51 proposal. Reproducible by clicking on the picture link and clicking `Share This` (or `Follow` if you haven't followed this proposal). Why is the image cropped?

Comment: It is definitely a bug. We gonna take a closer look at this ASAP. Thanks for reporting.